# Mulitple linkbuttons in user control needs to call event handler in the aspx page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-4.0

I have multiple user controls on a page and each of them have multiple linkbuttons that perform the same logic on the server side. Is there a way for all the linkbuttons to have the same event handler that is defined in the code behind of the page?

If needed, I can change the linkbuttons to be any other HTML or ASP.NET control as long as it can support a clickable image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your usercontrol create an event and wire it up. Then call it from the linkbuttons OnClick event handler:

UserControl.ascx:

```
<asp:LinkButton
runat="server"
id="linkbutton1"
OnClick="LinkButtonClicked">
Click Me
</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton
runat="server"
id="linkbutton2"
OnClick="LinkButtonClicked">
Click Me Again
</asp:LinkButton>
```

UserControl.ascx.cs

```
public event EventHandler UserControlLinkClick;

protected void LinkButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.UserControlLinkClick!= null)
       {
           this.UserControlLinkClick(this, e);
       }
}
```

Inside your parent page wire up the user controls UserControlLinkClick:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl uc = LoadControl("~/PathToUserControl.ascx");
    uc.UserControlLinkClick += new EventHandler(MyUserControl_UserControlLinkClick);
}

protected void MyUserControl_UserControlLinkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this code will execute when the usercontrol's LinkButtonClicked event is fired.
}
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Create an Event/Delegate in your custom control.  Then in your page code behind, you can add event handlers or subscribe methods to the delegate.

[Link for Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)

[Link for Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. I've never used events or delegates and would appreciate if you could provide a detailed answer.

Comment: @DotnetDude: Cognitronic did a good job of giving an example of how to use an event in a custom control.